# IIS 7.5: In the "Connect As" dialog, can't set "Specific user" to the application pool identity?

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-7.5, http-basic-authentication

I have a bunch of websites and applications with their own app pools, all using AppPoolIdentity. App pool identities are nice because you can set file system permissions and add SQL Server users based on them without having to manage any passwords.

My setup worked well until it was decided that these websites need to have basic authentication added to them. This would be fine, except that IIS absolutely *insists* on using the identity you present, rather than the configured app pool identity, regardless of any settings on the app pool itself.

The issue seems to lie in the `Connect As` dialog. I had it set to use `Application user (pass-through authentication)`. Confusing naming aside, this option obviously won't work for me. So I try to use `Specific user` instead.

The `Set Credentials` dialog is deceptive, in that it will accept an app pool user of the form `IIS AppPool\[appPool]` with no password, but when you go to access the site, you get this error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Config Error: Can not log on locally to `[websitePath]` as user `IIS AppPool\[appPool]` with virtual directory password

Config File: `\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\[appPool]\[websiteName].config`

Config Source

  153: `<application path="/" applicationPool="[appPool]">`

  154: `<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="[websitePath]" userName="IIS AppPool\[appPool]" />`

  155: `</application>`
```

[This is Microsoft's reference for the `<virtualDirectory>` element.](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) Opening this config file doesn't reveal anything helpful. I tried adding `password=""` to no avail.

Is there any way at all to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish? Ideally without adding a module or other special code to every site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by creating a stripped-down custom module based on [CustomBasicAuth](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/) and adding it at the server level (no configuration capabilities, since adding custom configuration at the machine level verges on onerous--you can't just reference a config section from an assembly like you can in web.config files). This required targeting .NET 2.0, strong-naming the assembly, and adding it to the GAC. I modified the code to only perform authentication, and to not set the user principal.